# Submitting EUR symbol in Form and getting extra 2 characters

Tags: java

When I submit a EUR (€) symbol from a Form in a JSP page to a Servlet, I get an extra 2 random characters.  (My IDE is IntelliJ).  Why are those other two characters submitted and is there something I'm missing?

I have a Form in a JSP page as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Euro Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/servlet" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtInput1" value="">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is handled by the following Servlet:

```
package servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = {"/servlet"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/form.jsp").include(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String txtInput1 = request.getParameter("txtInput1");

        char[] chars = txtInput1.toCharArray();
        // ...

        request.setAttribute("txtInput1", txtInput1);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/form.jsp").include(request, response);
    }

}
```

When I submit a EUR (€) symbol from that Form to the Servlet, I receive a random set of characters, 3 in fact, as shown below, but when I print it back out to the HTML page, it appears as a € symbol...:

[image]

Comment: It seems something to do with a unicode translation http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8320&number=128&names=-&utf8=dec

Comment: Great read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 0):

It is has to do with the unicode charset, infact in utf-8 (which is the charset you are using) the euro sign is encoded by the triplet 226 130 172

Comment: Should I be using a different charset?

Comment: I think [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is fine, it's a _variable   width character encoding_ so its perfectly normal that some characters are encoded with 1 byte and others (like the € sign) are encoded with 3 bytes